# GCC can not recognize Qt libraries or/and include files

Tags: c++, qt, gcc

I am trying to compile my Qt app from console. Here is specs:
MCBC 3.0 (has preinstalled Qt and gcc), Qt 4.6.4, gcc v4.1.2, qmake v2.01a.

My test qt app contains only 2 files: basket.pro and main.cpp.

basket.pro:

```
TARGET = basket
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
HEADERS +=
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    return a.exec();
}
```

I need to compile that app from console.

I got 2 virtual machines. VM #1 has installed QtCreator, and QtCreator compile this app without troubles, also app can be compiled from the console by "qmake" and "make". But there is VM#2, which does not have installed QtCreator, and it is where problems come from. 
I tried compile app by commands "qmake make", trying to use Makefile, created by QtCreator, trying to use only gcc comands with explicitly defined paths to Qt libs, include-files and linked libs, but always I got the same errors. For example, I use 2 gcc comands, which used by QtCreator for successful compile this app:

```
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/lib/qt46/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/lib/qt46/include/QtCore -I/usr/lib/qt46/include/QtGui -I/usr/lib/qt46/include -I. -o main.o main.cpp

g++ -o basket main.o -L/usr/lib/qt46/lib -lQtGui -L/usr/lib/qt46/lib -lQtCore -lpthread
```

And so after executing second command I got same error as always:

```
[root@ARM basket]# ./build_g++_step2
main.o: In function `basic_string<char, string_char_traits<char>, __default_alloc_template<true, 0> >::data(void) const':
/usr/lib/gcc-lib/i586-linux/2.95.4/../../../../include/g++-3/std/bastring.h:152: undefined reference to `QApplication::QApplication(int &, char **, int)'
/usr/lib/gcc-lib/i586-linux/2.95.4/../../../../include/g++-3/std/bastring.h:152: undefined reference to `QApplication::exec(void)'
/usr/lib/gcc-lib/i586-linux/2.95.4/../../../../include/g++-3/std/bastring.h:152: undefined reference to `QApplication::~QApplication(void)'
/usr/lib/gcc-lib/i586-linux/2.95.4/../../../../include/g++-3/std/bastring.h:152: undefined reference to `QApplication::~QApplication(void)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please tell what I missed.

Comment: I can see you are interesting why Qt version is so old. Well, it is not my choice. On my work we allowed to use only this Qt, because it is approved by special govervent organization in my country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GCC compiler is version 2.95 (a much too old version from the previous century, which is not conforming to C++11 standard, and which was known to be quite buggy), since `/usr/lib/gcc-lib/i586-linux/2.95.4/`is used. Run simply `g++ -v` or `g++ --version` to check the version of your compiler. (You could have some [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) issue, or you could have misinstalled your build tools).

You should upgrade your compiler to some much newer version (at least [GCC 6](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html) and preferably [GCC 7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html) in july 2017)

BTW, I recommend upgrading also your [Qt](http://qt.io/) library. Current version (in july 2017) is Qt5.9 and you should use some Qt5.

Then you need to regenerate your makefile, adding more in QT, as [answered by ilbeldus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45343456/841108)

Notice that you could use [pkg-config](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) to help compiling Qt applications (perhaps in your `Makefile`). You still need to explicitly use [moc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html). For example you might compile some Qt C++ GUI file `foo.cc` (after having used `moc`) with e.g.

```
 g++ -Wall -g -c $(pkg-config --cflags Qt5Gui) foo.c
```

and you would use `$(pkg-config --libs Qt5Gui)` for link options.

I don't recommend using your old MCBC thing (even with googling I didn't find what that is), notably if it is so obsolete.

Comment: Actually even the Qt version is ancient so they should work ok together

Comment: @IlBeldus no, it's not that ancient. Gcc  2.95 is a literally  from previous century.. Qt 4.6 requires  4.x compiler, 4.7 at very least if you want to use standard C++ classes support. Aside from not compiling at all, it may have some other problems and UBs,.. I kind have bad suspicion that you're on 2.6 kernel (based on the compiler version)  which isn't supported at all. Only time I saw  it is used on something newer, that was LynxOS 4, which had own (and very old-style) kernel based on old FreeBSD. And that was year 2005. If you have to use that toolchain, you 'd have to roll back to Qt 3.5

Comment: Thanks for noticing gcc incorrect version! That was realy helpful.

Comment: @FunnyHorse: feel free to accept my answer if it fits.

Comment: MCBC is russian military OS on base of unix. I agree with you with all my heart, it's totally obsolete, by it is not my dicision, unfortunatly.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the setup of the `QT` variable in your .pro file.

Add `QT += core gui` to it, re-run qmake and try to recompile

See the docs here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#qt

Comment: P.S. Why are you using Qt 4.6?! at least use 4.8 if you really can't switch to Qt5

Comment: Correct if I am wrong, but isn't this modules added by default?